# Redirect to android app with fallback

Tags: javascript, android, iframe

I have an android app that can handle custom links like my_app://blabla. I want to give an html to the client, that redirects him to app if it is installed, and redirecting him to custom web link otherwise.

First, I tried this sample

```
<html>    
    <head>        
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
        <script>            
            function startMyApp(){                
            document.location = '{% app_link %}';
              setTimeout( function()
              {
                document.location = '{% web_link %}';
              }, 300);               
            }            
        </script>        
    </head>    
    <body onload="startMyApp()">
    </body>   
</html>
```

But it strictly goes to the app, and client gets an error if no app is present without going to fallback url.

Next attempt is using iframe. It currently works with iPhone app, responding to the same link.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>   
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>App Redirection</title>
    </head>  
    <body>
      <iframe style="display:none" height="0" width="0" id="loader"></iframe>

      <script>(function(){
        var fallbackLink = '{% web_link %}';
        var appLink = '{% app_link %}';

        document.getElementById('loader').src = appLink;
        window.setTimeout(function (){ window.location.replace(fallbackLink); }, 1);
      })();</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here I suddenly found that native browser in android 4.* doesn't support iframe tag. So I need some other way to request an app link without losing control like in first example.

```
<img src=appLink>
```

and

```
<script src=appLink>
```

return ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME, so looks like it is not the way of requesting custom protocol.

Last I tried AJAX request with XMLHTTPRequest, as documentation says it supports non-http request too. Here's my sample

```
<!doctype html>
<html>    
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>App Redirection</title>
    </head>
    <body>       
      <script>(function(){
        var fallbackLink = '{% raw web_link %}';
        var appLink = '{% raw app_link %}';

        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', appLink, true);
        req.send(null);

        window.setTimeout(function (){ window.location.replace(fallbackLink); }, 1);
      })();</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works ok if appLink is http, but when I put an application link here I see no request sent.

So, am I missed some other opportunity to get this working, or this is really not a working case and I should send some more hate rays to android developers for not supporting iframes?

Comment: same struggling here